# can't rename mysql table

Tags: mysql, table-rename

I'm trying to rename my table using this SQL.  I'm using MySQL 5.1.41 on Windows XP.

```
USE 'bobby_tables';

    ALTER TABLE gc_acompte_fournisseur
      RENAME TO GC_Acompte_Fournisseur;
```

And the query claims to have executed correctly, but it lies!  My table name is still all lower case!

What foul arcanery have I run afoul of that forbids me from capitalizing my tables?

Comment: "Oh, yes. Little Bobby Tables, we call him." http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just how MySQL works on Windows:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names

> - lower_case_table_names
>
> If set to 0, table names are stored as
>   specified and comparisons are case
>   sensitive. If set to 1, table names
>   are stored in lowercase on disk and
>   comparisons are not case sensitive. If
>   set to 2, table names are stored as
>   given but compared in lowercase. This
>   option also applies to database names
>   and table aliases. For additional
>   information, see [Section 8.2.2,
>   “Identifier Case Sensitivity”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html).
>
> **You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system
>   that has case-insensitive file names
>   (such as Windows or Mac OS X)**. If
>   you set this variable to 0 on such a
>   system and access MyISAM tablenames
>   using different lettercases, index
>   corruption may result. **On Windows
>   the default value is 1**. On Mac OS X,
>   the default value is 2.
>
> **If you are using InnoDB tables, you should set this variable to 1 on all
>   platforms to force names to be
>   converted to lowercase**.

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: No. You should keep it at 1, and don't care what case your tables are. This is the safest way of handling this.

Comment: but the linux server has the tables in mixed case, giving my compare tool tons of false positives, and the captain doesn't want to make them lower case on the server :(

Comment: I see now. You can try setting it to 2, but I'm not sure if it will help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To rename/alter a table name in mysql, run following query:

RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name

Example:
RENAME TABLE `student` TO `pu_students`

For reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/rename-table.html

Thank you!